# Printing prime numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have to print the sequential 25 prime numbers after I ask the user to input a number. The code below indeed does print prime numbers but it prints empty spaces. I can't figure out how to make it print ONLY the prime numbers and no empty spaces. I have this thus far:

```
Public Function IsPrime(value)
Dim remainder As Double
Dim rounded As Long
Dim Max As Long
Dim j As Long

IsPrime = 0                                               
Max = 1 + Int(value / 2)                         
For j = 2 To Max                                     
   rounded = Int(value / j)                     
   remainder = (value / j) - rounded   

    If remainder = 0 Then
      Exit For
    End If

Next j

If j = Max + 1 Or value = 2 Then         
  IsPrime = 1
End If

If value <= 1 Then
  IsPrime = 0
End If

End Function



Public Sub printprime()
Dim x As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim matrix1(1 To 5, 1 To 5) As Integer


x = InputBox("Please enter a number ")
j = 1
For row = 1 To 5
  For col = 1 To 5
    If IsPrime(x + j) = 1 Then
      Cells(row, col) = x + j
      matrix1(row, col) = Cells(row, col)
    End If
    j = j + 1
  Next col
Next row
```

Comment: I suggest that you begin by filling numbers on only one row. You should increment the column number only if a prime is found. When you've got that working, modify it to fill by row and column. Hint: the mod function will help for the latter.

Comment: where do i put the increment to instruct it to increment only if a prime is found? @AndrewMorton

Comment: nevermind, i figured that out! @AndrewMorton

Comment: could using a Do While be helpful in restricting the columns and numbers? @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep going and only record the primes:

```
Public Sub printprime()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim j As Long

    x = InputBox("Please enter a number ")

    row = 1
    col = 1
    For j = x + 1 To 9999
        If IsPrime(j) Then
            Cells(row, col) = j
            col = col + 1
            If col = 6 Then
                col = 1
                row = row + 1
            End If
            If row = 7 Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have to incorporate a matrix, like I was attempting to do so in my post. Any help with that?

Comment: it is better to loop for till found 20 prime number, not 9999. input number can be 9000 and it might not find 20 prime number in that interval. You can insert an increment in isPrime part.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version

```
Sub print_prime()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim if_prime As Boolean
    Dim Count
    
    Count = InputBox("Enter Max Number")
    
    For i = 2 To Count
        if_prime = True
        If i = 2 Then GoTo nextItem
        For j = 2 To i - 1
            If i Mod j = 0 Then
                if_prime = False
                GoTo nextItem
            End If
        Next j
nextItem:
        If if_prime Then Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```