# Determine prime number from specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I have a specified list of numbers from 1 to 100 in column A (i.e. A1:A100) on excel spreadsheet. I want my code to print the result of whether it is a prime number [output: "Prime" or "Not Prime"] next to each number 1 to 100 in column B on the same worksheet. This is what I have so far. The logic works but the problem is that the code does not seem to be looping after n=1. Any suggestion how to make this work?

```
Sub primenumber()

Dim i As Integer
Dim divisor As Integer

Dim rng As Range, n As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


For Each n In rng
Debug.Print n
    divisor = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        If n Mod i = 0 Then
        divisor = divisor + 1
        End If
    Next i
    'Debug.Print i
        If divisor = 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Prime"
        Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Not Prime"
        End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Why check for divisibility by every number in the range? That is extremely inefficient. If you see that 100 mod 2 = 0, there is no good reason to still check 100 mod 3, 100 mod 4, ... etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120382/write-prime-numbers-between-1-to-100-through-vba-coding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826904/how-to-check-for-prime-numbers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562318/printing-prime-numbers

Comment: Have you researched this? How to do this is well documented on this site already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bu if you want to just see what needs changing in your original program to make it work

Sorry, you said you already had numbers 1-100 in A1:A100 so the only issue is that all the results are going to B1 at the moment.

So otherwise the logic is fine and you can get it working just with a couple of changes:

```
Sub primenumber()

Dim i As Integer
Dim divisor As Integer

Dim rng As Range, n As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


For Each n In rng
Debug.Print n
    divisor = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        If n Mod i = 0 Then
        divisor = divisor + 1
        End If
    Next i
    'Debug.Print i
        If divisor = 2 Then
        n.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Prime"
        Else
        n.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Prime"
        End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With 1 through 100 in **A1** through **A100**, give this a try:

```
Sub primenumber()
    With Range("B2")
        .FormulaArray = "=IF(OR(A2=2,A2=3),""prime"",IF(AND((MOD(A2,ROW(INDIRECT(""2:""&A2-1)))<>0)),""prime"",""not prime""))"
    End With
    Range("B2").Copy Range("B3:B100")
    Range("B2:B100").Value = Range("B2:B100").Value
End Sub
```